# Quarter-step volume adjustments not working on 2016 MacBook Pro running Sierra

Tags: macos, audio, macbook, macos-sierra

I have previously been able to use `shift+option+volume up/down` to make quarter-step adjustments to the volume. On my new 2016 MacBook Pro with Touch Bar running macOS 10.12.2 this no longer works.

Curiously, I have noticed that when an external keyboard is attached, adding `fn` to that combination does the trick. But that's not useful on the MacBook's keyboard since the `fn` key toggles the control strip on the touch bar so that the volume button is not longer available.

Any ideas?